# Outputing multiple file from a filtered single file

Tags: powershell, scripting

Hi I have filtered some log file, and then outtputed the results in a file, "E:\filtered_$now.log" i have reviewed this file and has contents and logs in it, then I want to create multiple files from the filtered file and store them in different folders, but it doesn't work, the files created are empty, can anyone identify my problem?

```
$now = (get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss).ToString()

(filtering and deleting some fields....)

Out-File "E:\filtered_$now.log" |  #output in a file 

#UPTIME
Get-Content "E:\filtered_$now.log" |  #use the outputed file to further filtering
where { $_ -match "_Uptime"} |
Out-File "E:\uptime\uptime_$now.log" |

#MEMORY
Get-Content "E:\filtered_$now.log" |
where { $_ -match "_Memoria"} |
Out-File "E:\memoria\memory_$now.log" |

#SWAP
Get-Content "E:\filtered_$now.log" |
where { $_ -match "_Memoria_Swap"} |
Out-File "E:\swap\swap_$now.log"
```

some examples in the filtered file

```
10:41:41 03/02/2020 name:somemonitor_Uptime targets:some.target state:System\System Up Time=4087333.07102 System\System Up Time=4087333.07102 type:Windows Resources unique:1950544758

10:41:41 03/02/2020 name:somemonitor_Memoria targets:some.target state:86% virtual memory used, 6608MB virtual memory free, 1921.99245 pages/sec metrics:percent used=86primMB free=6608;pages/sec=1921.992449537446;virtual memory used %=86;virtual memory MB free=6608;physical memory used %=n/a;physical memory MB free=n/a type:Memory unique:1950492661

10:41:43 03/02/2020 name:Somemonitor_Memoria_Swap targets:some.target state:3% swap space used, 3829MB swap space free, 0 pages/sec; 69% physical memory used, 9668MB physical memory free metrics:percent used=3primMB free=3829;pages/sec=0.0;swap space used %=3;swap space MB free=3829;physical memory used %=69;physical memory MB free=9668 type:Memory unique:1950647593
```

Comment: Your code seems fine so far. Are you sure about the patterns that you use for matching? Can you show in a minimal example, what the content of the `filtered_$now.log` would look like?

Comment: You are a bit too liberal with the pipes.  You are piping every command to the next command in the script.  Try using $something = Get-Content...| Where-Object ..., then $something | out-file ...  Don't keep piping to every section, i.e. UPTIME is seperate from MEMORY and is seperate from SWAP.

Comment: Hi, @ManuelBatsching yes I added some examples of the logs

Comment: The very first pipeline in your script (`Out-File "E:\filtered_$now.log" |`) doesn't make any sense. What's the input to `Out-File`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example of the Filtered log this may be what you are looking for:

...Previous Commands

```
$filteredLog = Get-Content "E:\filtered_$now.log"

#UPTIME
$filteredLog | Where-Object {$_ -match "_Uptime"} | Out-file "E:\uptime\uptime_$now.log"

#MEMORY
$filteredLog | Where-Object {$_ -match "_Memoria"} | Out-file "E:\uptime\memory_$now.log"

#SWAP
$filteredLog | Where-Object {$_ -match "_Swap"} | Out-file "E:\uptime\swap_$now.log"
```